# Handbrake refuses to use correct Audio channel with batch conversions

Tags: handbrake

I'm trying to make Handbrake convert a batch of .mkv files, but I'm running into a problem where everything that it spits out from batch transfers uses the default channel 1, but I want the resulting files to use channel 2. This happens no matter which audio channel I choose when starting the conversion. Does anyone know what the hell is going on?

Comment: Maybe if you tell us in which way you are using Handbrake (GUI or CLI) and what settings you apply, someone can help you. You can edit your message to add these informations.

Comment: Also you could try to get as much log information out of the process as possible, as at some point a command is/isnt being issued that possibly you could correct for your needs.